# R Marginal Formats

Tags: r, margins, contingency

I was wondering if anyone can help? I have created a contingency table and have added margins using the following:

```
addmargins(sn.tab)
```

I was wondering how to format the margins as percentages instead of sums for each column.

Comment: Percentage of what? The sum across *all* values? Please make your example reproducible by adding some sample data.

Comment: You should check the janitor package (github version) - it has some nice tools for adorning tables of counts with various quantities:https://github.com/sfirke/janitor .

Comment: There doesn't seem to enough information here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the percentage of total, you can explicitly specify a `FUN` argument in `addmargins`:

```
# Sample data
tab <- matrix(c(10, 90, 40, 60), ncol = 2, byrow = T);

addmargins(tab, FUN = function(x) sum(x) / sum(tab));
#Margins computed over dimensions
#in the following order:
#1:
#2:
#                                        function(x) sum(x)/sum(tab)
#                            10.00 90.00                       0.500
#                            40.00 60.00                       0.500
#function(x) sum(x)/sum(tab)  0.25  0.75                       0.005
```

Or if you only want the percentage of total per column:

```
addmargins(tab, FUN = list(perc.total = function(x) sum(x) / sum(tab), sum));
#Margins computed over dimensions
#in the following order:
#1:
#2:
#                       sum
#           10.00 90.00 100
#           40.00 60.00 100
#perc.total  0.25  0.75   1
```